# What is the best way to deal with "_d" suffix for C extensions when using debug build?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm trying to debug my C extension for Python 2.7. I use python2.7 debug build. I build my project with `setuptools` and my `setup.py` has such lines:

```
ext_modules=[Extension("my.extension",
                       ["my/_extension.c"])]
```

When I invoke `python setup.py install` for some reason extension compiles to a file with `_d` suffix, and after that, in Python, I can't do `import my.extension`, I can only do `import my.extension_d`. And what I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/my/extension_d.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/my/extension_d.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initextension_d)
```

Of course my extension does not have `initextension_d`, it only has `initextension` function.

This is very incovenient, because I have to change some code and add this `_d` suffix to imports and other stuff.

Is it possible to turn off prepending of this suffix? Or how to deal with that problem in other way? Maybe there are some "official" ways?

### UPDATE #0

I use Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: On what platform do you see this? Your traceback mentions `linux`. Windows is the only platform that uses `_d` for debug builds. See my attempt below to give an answer for the Windows platform (which you may not have meant).

Comment: You should post the output of `python setup.py install`.

Comment: And maybe `setup.py` itself and the value of `os.name`. I'm also wondering about the `.py` extension. It should by `.pyd` or `.so` ...

Answer (score 3):

Just disable debug mode when build C Extension.
Or, if you do like to keep debug info, temporary disable `_DEBUG` macro:

```cpp
#ifdef _DEBUG
# ifndef BOOST_DEBUG_PYTHON
#  ifdef _MSC_VER  
    // VC8.0 will complain if system headers are #included both with
    // and without _DEBUG defined, so we have to #include all the
    // system headers used by pyconfig.h right here.
#   include <stddef.h>
#   include <stdarg.h>
#   include <stdio.h>
#   include <stdlib.h>
#   include <assert.h>
#   include <errno.h>
#   include <ctype.h>
#   include <wchar.h>
#   include <basetsd.h>
#   include <io.h>
#   include <limits.h>
#   include <float.h>
#   include <string.h>
#   include <math.h>
#   include <time.h>
#  endif
#  undef _DEBUG // Don't let Python force the debug library just because we're debugging.
#  define DEBUG_WRAP_PYTHON_H
# endif
#endif

#include <Python.h>

#ifdef DEBUG_WRAP_PYTHON_H
# define _DEBUG
#endif
```

For full code sample you may take a look on [full version](https://github.com/mirror/boost/blob/master/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp) of how boost.python includes `python.h`.

Answer (score 2):

A comment from the distutils source file of `build_ext.py`:

> # extensions in debug_mode are named 'module_d.pyd' under windows

It's the same for C Extensions, so there shouldn't be any problem. But since there's one, it's also possible to remove the `_d` suffix:

```
import os.path
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def get_ext_filename(self, ext_name):
        fn = _build_ext.get_ext_filename(self, ext_name)
        fn = os.path.splitext(fn)
        if fn[0].endswith('_d'):
            fn[0] = fn[0][:-2]
        return fn[0] + fn[1]
```

Or just disable debug for a while:

```
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def get_ext_filename(self, ext_name):
        debug, self.debug = self.debug, False
        fn = _build_ext.get_ext_filename(self, ext_name)
        self.debug = debug
        return fn
```

Don't forget to set the `cmdclass` within `setup`:

```
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ...
)
```

I'm not using Windows myself, so it's just a wild guess, but maybe you're mixing debug and release parts of Python.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can define in your C module function

```
void initextension_d()
{ initextension(); }
```

Comment: @fpbhb Why you think so?

Comment: because you will end up having loaded a debug build of the extension into a non-debug build of the interpreter which use mutually incompatible runtime libraries. I have tried to explain that in my answer.

Comment: @fpbhb Quote from your answer: _All that said, it is not necessary to use a debug build of Python to debug Python extensions, unless you plan to use the debugging features of msvcrtd.dll_ Why did you decide that the author works with Visual C++ compiler?

Comment: Apparently because Windows is the only platform where Python extension modules are named differently for debug builds (adding  `_d`). OTOH, you are right, the question mentions `linux-x86` in the traceback ... perhaps we should ask the questioner?

Comment: ... and maybe "Gill Bates" made me think "Windows", too ;-)

Comment: BTW, simply providing multiple entry points is not addressing the root cause of this problem on Linux either.